# TCPDF 6.2.8 won't makes Bar/QR codes (6.0.093 works just fine)

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, tcpdf

When creating a PDF with a barcode and QR code, it works completely fine with tcpdf v 6.0.093, but just switching to v 6.2.8 makes the barcodes and qr codes not work.

Literally, I can just swap out the folders back and forth - it works on 6.0.93 and it doesn't on 6.2.8.

Any thoughts as to what could be causing this?

**Code:**

```
$pdf = new XTCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, 'Letter', true, 'ISO-8859-1', false); 
$diskcache=false, $pdfa=false)
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins($pageMargin, $pageMargin, $pageMargin); //PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, $pageMargin/2);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 10, '', true); //was dejavusans, helvetica - changed to helvetica as a recommended performance improvement
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setJPEGQuality(70);

$html = '
    <table style="border:10px solid #eee; padding:0;" cellspacing="20">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>  ... MORE HTML ...';

$html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="' . $barcodeParams . '" />';
$html .= '<tcpdf method="write2DBarcode" params="' . $qrcodeParams . '" /><br>';

// ...

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdfPath = APP . 'tmp' . DS . 'pdfs' . DS . 'pdf_12345.pdf';
$pdf->Output($pdfPath, 'F');
```